# How to count Notification of Any application

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Hello i make one example which show count of notification which user got, with help of **NotificationListenerService** what i actually implemented yet...

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        final String pkgnm = sbn.getPackageName();
        int ID = sbn.getId();


    }
```

but my problem is some application notify twice and also there time milisec is different and key also different.

So how can i filter the notification only once.

Thanks in Advance